# Why does Vector skin have an invisible h2 with text 'Navigation menu' by setting css top: -9999?

Tags: html, mediawiki

I've seen the invisible heading on another site where the content is the name of the site but the css is a more thorough;

```
visibility: hidden, text-indent: -9999em etc
```

I'm wondering because I'm modifying the Vector skin to use as my site's skin, and I was changing html around it.

Is it there for accessibility? Screen readers? Whats the merit of it?

Here it is from source of a wikipedia page:

```
<div id="mw-navigation">
        <h2>Navigation menu</h2>

        <div id="mw-head">
                                <div id="p-personal" role="navigation" class="" aria-labelledby="p-personal-label">
                    <h3 id="p-personal-label">Personal tools</h3>
```

Comment: This is one of the popular methods for replacing the image with plain text on devices that do not support CSS. Google "CSS image replacement" for lots of discussion about it.

Comment: Ok thanks, sometimes its hard to know what to search for.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done both for accessibility and SEO reasons if the header is replaced by an image. In the normal state, the image will be seen as the header, if read by a screenreader, the text content will make clear what it is about.

Comment: Ahh I thought it might be something like that, thanks. I +1 you but I need 2 more reputation for it to publicly show.